# Can I simultaneously populate non-consecutive columns in a numpy array when they are not evenly spaced?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the following numpy array

```
A = np.zeros(7,10)
```

**Question** Can I simultaneously populate non-consecutive columns with a given value or given set of values?  For example if I wanted to replace A[:,3:6] and A[:,8] with the integer 1 I could do something like this.

```
A[:,3:6] = 1 
A[:,8] = 1
```

But I was just wondering if there was a way to accomplish this for multiple non-consecutive columns simultaneously?  These non-consecutive columns would not necessarily be evenly spaced out so I couldn't could use the start:stop:step method in the index.

Comment: `A[:, [3,4,5,8]]=1`

Comment: Thanks again @hpaulj!  So I take it there is no way to incorporate a range of columns along with a singular column value without looping as noted in the answer below. e.g. to assign A[ :,3:N] = Value and A[:, N+X] = Value, there's no vectorized approach?

Comment: There isn't a slice expression if that's what you are aiming for.  Either you select with your individual entries, or you combine them into one list/array first.  If you can only specify the action with a list of disimilar items, it's unlikely that simple slicing will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index of the non-consecutive rows, you can do this:

```
A = np.zeros((7,10))
rows = [1,2,5]
A[rows, 3:6] = 1
A[rows, 8] = 1

print(A)

#output:    
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

UPDATE: In response to your updated question and comment, if you want to modify all rows for certain non-consecutive columns and use the convenience of slice notation, you can do the following: Make a list of tuples with each tuple representing a slice of the columns.  Even a single column would be represented by a slice. Then you would iterate through the column slices:

```
A = np.zeros((7,10))
col_slices = [(3,6),(8,9)]
for s in col_slices:
    A[:, s[0]:s[1]] = 1
print(A)

#output:   
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Finally, you can combine both of the above techniques to alter the desired rows and columns simultaneously:

```
A = np.zeros((7,10))
rows = [1,2,5]
col_slices = [(3,6),(8,9)]
for s in col_slices:
    A[rows, s[0]:s[1]] = 1
print(A)

#output:   
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

UPDATE 2: If you want to use non-consecutive slices in a vectorized way, you can first define a function that converts a dictionary of slices to a list of indexes, then use the output of that function in a vectorized way.  Either one of the functions below will accomplish this:

```
#function 1
def slice_to_index(dic):
    """
    :param dic: dictionary where key is the start and value is the end of each slice
    :return: list of indexes
    """
    l = []
    for k,v in dic.items():
        l.extend(list(range(k,v)))
    return l

#function 2
def slice_to_index(dic):
    return list(np.concatenate([list(range(k,v)) for k,v in dic.items()]).flat)

A = np.zeros((7,10))
A[:,slice_to_index({3:6, 8:9})] = 1

print(A)

#output:
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: thank you very much this is incredibly helpful.  I had a typo in my original question but i assume this would work for columns as well so it wouldn't make much difference.  I was wondering however is there a way to maintain the range notation while naming the columns.  That is to say currently we would have col = [3,4,5,8] but is there a way to do it so it would be more akin to col = [3:6,8] because the actual column index would be something like 3:100 , 105, 106, 110, where it would be quite tedious to list each one out individually.

Comment: awesome thank you so much!  Just wondering can the latter portion be vectorized without the need for loops?

Comment: Yes. See my Update 2. Consider accepting the answer if it meets your needs.